# Как отправить выбранный чекбокс

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Есть код, который отправляет введенное значение input в базу. Но необходимо еще, чтобы в базу отправлялся один из выбранных чекбоксов. К примру если выбран чекбокс Vkontakte, то в базу поступало значение Vkontakte, соответственно если выбран чекбокс Facebook, то в базу нужно отправить слово Facebook

```
<form method="post" action="" id="contactform"> 

    <input type='text' id="emailus" name='email' placeholder="Enter your ID">

    <label class="container1">Facebook
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" value="Facebook">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container1">Vkontakte
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Vkontakte">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container1">Instagram
      <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Instagram">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label> 
                       <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send">

    </form>


if(isset($_POST['add_email']) && $_POST['add_email'] != ''){
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['add_email']);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user_info(mailus, chekbox) VALUES('$email','$chek')";

  if(mysqli_query($connection,$sql)){
    echo '<div class="suc_reg"><p style="color:#009219">Успешно</p></div>';
  }else{
    echo '<div class="warn_reg"><p id="form-error">Неудача, попробуйте снова</p></div>';
  }
}


$('#submit').click(function(){

  if(email == ''){
    $('#message').html('<div class="warn_reg"><p id="form-error">Введите ваш ID</p></div>');
  }else{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:'user.php',
      data:'add_email='+email,
      success:function(msg){
        $('#message').html(msg);
          document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true; 
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data: {
  add_email: $("#emailus").val(),
  add_check: $("#contactform input[name='radio']:checked").val()
},

$check = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['add_check']);
```